# LWC data Table long text in cell

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

I created a data table using a LWC. But my table is behaving weird when the user write big text
see example below
[image]

As you can see the table is out of the card giving a very bad user experience
Would it be possible to or break line according to the column size or to hide some of the text ???

here is my html code:

```
    <div class="slds-p-around_x-small">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="">
                        <th class="slds-size_3-of-12" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Name</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-size_1-of-12" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Number_of_Keys">Number of keys</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-size_3-of-12" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Neighbourhood">Neighbourhood</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-size_2-of-12" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="LeadSource">LeadSource</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="slds-size_3-of-12" scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Status">Status</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
                <template for:each = {myList} for:item = "item" for:index="indexVar">
                    <tr key={item.key} class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <td class="slds-size_3-of-12" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  title="Prospecting">
                                <template if:false={isEdited}>
                                    {item.Name}
                                   </template>
                                <template if:true={isEdited}>
                                    <lightning-input key={item.key} data-id={item.Id} name="input1" label="Name" value={item.Name} variant="label-hidden" onchange={handleNameChange}></lightning-input>
                                </template>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="slds-size_1-of-10" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  title="Prospecting">
                                <template if:false={isEdited}>{item.Number_of_Keys__c}</template>
                                <template if:true={isEdited}>
                                    test
                                </template>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="slds-size_3-of-12" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div title="Prospecting">
                                <template if:false={isEdited}>{item.Neighbourhood__c}</template>
                                <template if:true={isEdited}>
                                    test
                                </template>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="slds-size_2-of-12" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  title="Prospecting">
                                <template if:false={isEdited}> 
                                    {item.Neighbourhood__c}
                                </template>
                                <template if:true={isEdited}>
                                   test
                                </template>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="slds-size_3-of-10" data-label="Prospecting">
                            <div  title="Prospecting">
                                <template if:false={isEdited}> 
                                    {item.Status}
                                </template>
                                <template if:true={isEdited}>
                                    <c-edit-picklist 
                                    unique-key={item.Id}
                                    object-api-name="Lead"
                                    selected-value={item.Status}
                                    onpicklistchange={handlePicklistChange}>
                                    </c-edit-picklist>
                                   test
                                </template>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The natural behavior of a HTML table is to expand the columns to fit the max width of the content.

To override this add this class to your table element:

```
slds-table_fixed-layout
```

The css style this class adds `table-layout: fixed;` is what stops it from expanding.

Comment: ok if I add slds-table_fixed-layout on my td I add slds-truncate it is now working
is there a way to not have it truncate but break line?

Comment: You have to remove the slds-truncate class you have inside your td elements. Also, you would need to override some of the white-space styles on the default table. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: you are the best working perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SLDS Truncation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/truncation/) if you want to truncate the extra text. For example you can add the class like `slds-has-flexi-truncate`.

Or if you want to wrap it using CSS.

```
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: where should I put it slds-has-flexi-truncate ? I tried on every item nothing seems to work ...

Comment: @Ben2pop put it on `<td>`